# Android Studio can't compile, but gradle cli CAN compile

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio, gradlew

I have strange error with Android Studio 0.5.7 on Mac. I can't compile my project with gradle and ndk-build. It fails with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':SKG:ndkBuild'.
A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build''
```

**BUT,** when I run ./gradlew compileArmDebugJava from CLI, project is **sucessfully compiled**.

error in android studio:

```
    Executing tasks: [:SKG:compileArmDebugJava]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:SKG:preBuild
:SKG:preArmDebugBuild
:SKG:checkArmDebugManifest
:SKG:preArmReleaseBuild
:SKG:preArmv7DebugBuild
:SKG:preArmv7ReleaseBuild
:SKG:preFatDebugBuild
:SKG:preFatReleaseBuild
:SKG:preMipsDebugBuild
:SKG:preMipsReleaseBuild
:SKG:preX86DebugBuild
:SKG:preX86ReleaseBuild
:SKG:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71910Library UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:prepareArmDebugDependencies
:SKG:compileArmDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:compileArmDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateArmDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:mergeArmDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateArmDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:mergeArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:processArmDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:processArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateArmDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':SKG:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.103 secs
```

successful build from cli

```
./gradlew compileArmDebugJava
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:SKG:preBuild
:SKG:preArmDebugBuild
:SKG:checkArmDebugManifest
:SKG:preArmReleaseBuild
:SKG:preArmv7DebugBuild
:SKG:preArmv7ReleaseBuild
:SKG:preFatDebugBuild
:SKG:preFatReleaseBuild
:SKG:preMipsDebugBuild
:SKG:preMipsReleaseBuild
:SKG:preX86DebugBuild
:SKG:preX86ReleaseBuild
:SKG:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71910Library UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:prepareArmDebugDependencies
:SKG:compileArmDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:compileArmDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateArmDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:mergeArmDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateArmDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:mergeArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:processArmDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:processArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateArmDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:ndkBuild
make: Entering directory `/...my path.../SKG/src/main/jni'
[armeabi] Install        : libcrypto.so => libs/armeabi/libcrypto.so
[armeabi] Install        : libdatabase_sqlcipher.so => libs/armeabi/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
[armeabi] Install        : libgenerate.so => libs/armeabi/libgenerate.so
[armeabi] Install        : libsqlcipher_android.so => libs/armeabi/libsqlcipher_android.so
[armeabi] Install        : libssl.so => libs/armeabi/libssl.so
[armeabi] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => libs/armeabi/libstlport_shared.so
make: Leaving directory `/...my path.../src/main/jni'
:SKG:compileArmDebugJava UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 16.327 secs
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 28
        versionName "2.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }

    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "generate"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        mips {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "mips"
            }
        }
        armv7 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
        fat
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}

// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni/').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question instead of embedding it in the question to make it clearer to others that you found a solution.

Comment: at the time, when I figure it out, I wasn't able to answer my question, because I hat low score to do that.

Comment: I have the same problem even when I set my file path to have no trailing slash. huh.

Comment: what system do you use ? windows ? linux ?

Comment: For me the "libs/armeabi-v7a/libmylibrary.so" file gets generated into the /jni/ folder which is wrong, it should go on directory up. Is there any way to generate them in the proper folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved, removed last '/', changed line from this:

```
commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni/').absolutePath
```

to this:

```
commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
```

Comment: For answering your own question.

Answer (score 2):

If u are using windows u need write this in gradle.build: `commandLine ndkCommand,'-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,'clean'`

But if u used another OS like Linux or Mac u need write this:
`commandLine ndkCommand,'-C', file('src/main/jni/').absolutePath,'clean'`